# How do I split on multiple white space or tabs?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, split, whitespace

Hey in Ruby how do you split on multiple white space or a tab character?  I tried this

```
2.4.0 :003 > a = "b\tc\td"
 => "b\tc\td" 
2.4.0 :005 > a.strip.split(/([[:space:]][[:space:]]+|\t)/)
 => ["b", "\t", "c", "\t", "d"]
```

but the tabs themselves are getting turned into tokens and that's not what I want.  The above should return

```
["b", "c", "d"]
```

Comment: using `\s+` pattern for split function, will return what you want. usage: `.split(/\s+/)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because the group you used is a *capturing* one. See [`split` reference](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-split):

> If *pattern* contains groups, the respective matches will be returned in the array as well.

Use a [**non-capturing group**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon) (used only for grouping patterns) to avoid adding matched strings into the resulting array:

```
a.strip.split(/(?:[[:space:]][[:space:]]+|\t)/)
                ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

In this instance you can use a character class that includes both spaces and tabs in your regular expression:

```
"b\tc\td".split /[ \t]+/
```

If you want to split on any whitespace, you can also use the `[\s]+` notation, which matches all whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

There are some easy approaches than accepted solution:

```
a.strip.split("\s")
```

or

```
a.split("\s")
```

'\s' will take care for multiple whitespaces characters.

for above case you can simply use:

```
a = "b\tc\td" 
a.split("\t")    #=> ["b", "c", "d"]
```

or for combination of multiple spaces and tabs

```
a.gsub("\t", " ").split("\s")     #=> ["b", "c", "d"]
```